# "IMYY4UECAPS↑(111...(1)...1)" Rebus

Tags: rebus

I was solving some puzzle where I got a password to crack and found hint of it as $``IMYY4UECAPS\uparrow(111...(1)...1)\text{''}$

Some of the things i found out there is SPACE written in opposite order

or the numbers 1's in the bracket denote the letters corresponding is there means : IMY(E)S may be.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn you first badge? Just a question - is the puzzle from an ongoing competition?

Comment: no i am reading some cipher texts

Comment: which cipher text did this question come from?

Comment: I think this starts with [rot13](http://www.rot13.com) V'z gbb jvfr sbe lbh

Comment: For content that is not your own, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)**. Using someone else's content without (at minimum) disclosing where it came from is plagiarism, and such posts are deleted.

Comment: I guess the SPACE backwards could refer to backspace